# How to get the raw command line arguments

Tags: c++, c, windows

I need to pass command line arguments from A.exe to B.exe. If A.exe with multi-args like

`A.exe -a="a" -b="b"'`

and I can use

`BeginProcess("B.exe", **args!**)`

to start B.exe.
How can I get the raw command line arguments like

`'-a="a" -b="b"'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the raw command line.

Note that GetCommandLine also includes argv[0]. So you will have to go beyond argv[0] from the output of GetCommandLine before passing it to B.

This is some non-error checked code to do that

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LPTSTR cmd  = GetCommandLine();

    int l = strlen(argv[0]);

    if(cmd == strstr(cmd, argv[0]))
    {
        cmd = cmd + l;
        while(*cmd && isspace(*cmd))
            ++cmd;
    }

    std::cout<<"Command Line is : "<<cmd;

}
```

When I run the above program as `A.exe -a="a" -b="b"`, I get the following output

```
A.exe -a="a" -b="b"
Command Line is : -a="a" -b="b"
```

Comment: For completeness, note that in this particular case you don't necessarily have to separate out the first part of the command line.  The CreateProcess function allows you to specify the executable explicitly rather than as part of the command line.

Comment: Don't use this code. It will fail if the executable name is enclosed in quotes (which can happen even if there are no spaces in its path). For a correct implementation, look at [Wine's implementation of CommandLineToArgvW](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/shell32/shell32_main.c). @harry-johnston: you still need to remove the executable path in order to replace it with the program you want to run, unless you're spawning a copy of yourself.

Comment: @benrg: no, you don't, that was my point.  If you explicitly specify the executable via the `lpApplicationName` argument, the executable specified in the `lpCommandLine` argument is ignored.

Comment: @harry-johnston: from memory, and my reading of [the CreateProcess documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if lpApplicationName is not NULL then lpCommandLine contains only the arguments, so the old executable name will end up as argv[1] if you don't remove it.

Comment: @benrg: no, the command line is passed to the application as-is, so you still need to specify an application name for argv[0].  (It just doesn't have to be the *actual* application name.)  From the docs: "Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line."  I have code that relies on this behaviour, so I can confirm from personal experience that this is how it works. :-)

Comment: @benrg: on the other hand, you're absolutely right about needing to cope with quoted paths.  I don't know how I missed that when first reading this answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the one and only correct way to skip the executable name, based on [Wine's implementation of CommandLineToArgvW](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/7ec5f555b05152dda53b149d5994152115e2c623/dlls/shell32/shell32_main.c#L58):

```
char *s = lpCmdline;
if (*s == '"') {
    ++s;
    while (*s)
        if (*s++ == '"')
            break;
} else {
    while (*s && *s != ' ' && *s != '\t')
        ++s;
}
/* (optionally) skip spaces preceding the first argument */
while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t')
    s++;
```

**Note**! Current Wine implementation, as of Feb 19 2'20 - git commit `a10267172`, is now moved from [`dlls/shell32/shell32_main.c`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/a10267172046fc16aaa1cd1237701f6867b92fc0/dlls/shell32/shell32_main.c) to [`dlls/shcore/main.c`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/a10267172046fc16aaa1cd1237701f6867b92fc0/dlls/shcore/main.c#L259).

Comment: Why is there not any need to handle escaped quotes?

Comment: @JoshuaPerrett There is no escaping mechanism. There's no need for one because the executable name is a filesystem path, and Win32 paths can't contain quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition of `main` is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

The `argv` variable contains the command-line arguments. The `argc` variable indicates how many entries in the `argv` array are used.

Comment: Yes, this is right. But I need to join argv to a single string.

Comment: @miaodadao If you are using C++, that can be done quite easily with a for loop and std::string. If you are using C, look at the `strcat()` function.

Comment: That approach tends to mangle the command line if the syntax isn't fairly simple.  As a trivial example, you lose multiple spaces between arguments.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, why would you lose multiple spaces? `std::string(argv[1])+argv[2]` preserves whatever spaces are in the arguments. Do you mean the new process can't reliably separate the arguments again? If so, that was exactly my criticism in the comments to PotatoSwatter's answer ... passing `argv` preserves individual arguments, concatenating and resplitting doesn't.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: in Microsoft C, at least, whitespace is trimmed from argv[], so concatenating argv[1] and argv[2] loses any whitespace that was originally between argument 1 and argument 2.  GetCommandLine preserves the whitespace exactly as it was originally passed.  (Of course, *most* of the time it's OK to do argv[1] + " " + argv[2] because the new process is probably going to discard any extra whitespace anyway.  But there are edge cases.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I find it difficult to imagine a situation where mangling the whitespace between arguments matters. One solution to make sure the arguments can be reliably separated again is to insert quotes around each one as you concatenate them. As long as the individual arguments are preserved, does it matter that the whitespace in between them is not?

Comment: I have a couple of homegrown applications where whitespace between tokens is significant, because doing so considerably simplifies the syntax, but I can't point to any mainstream ones off the top of my head.  I don't think the whitespace is the only potential issue, it's just the one that required the least thought.  Inserting quotes isn't safe unless you understand the child program's syntax; remember that in Windows, the child program, not the shell or OS, parses the command line, so the quotes could change the meaning.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point about the quotes. I certainly can imagine situations where escaping characters in the arguments can be even more complicated than my simplistic suggested solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, I believe the correct solution is to call GetCommandLine() to get your full commandline, and then [PathGetArgs(CommandLine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathgetargsw) to remove arg0 (your exe path) from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The raw string typed into the shell is converted by the shell into `argv` before your program begins running. I've never heard of an operating system or shell providing a "raw" command-line in addition to `argv`.

What if the user used quotes to pass a space character into your arguments? What if they used a backslash to escape a quote inside the quotes? Different shells may even have different quoting rules.

If you have a list like `argv`, you should try to find an API that accepts that rather than attempting to implement string processing which is only auxiliary to the actual goal. Microsoft is serious about security and they certainly provide something that doesn't require adding a security hole to your application.

I can't find documentation about any C/C++ API `BeginProcess`; I'm kind of assuming this is Windows but in any case you should double check your platform's reference manual for an alternative system call.

Comment: _I've never heard of an operating system or shell providing a "raw" command-line in addition to `argv`._ Win32 provides it via [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) (and presumably you have to parse it yourself ... eurgh! how primitive!)  I assume `BeginProcess` is meant to be `CreateProcess`

Comment: @JonathanWakely hehe, usually I avoid hearing more things about Windows, but it looks like I slipped up this time :D . Hmm, following the link it sounds like they provide a parser function too, and it was introduced in Windows XP so perhaps the string is sanitized already. M$ seems to introduce APIs mainly in response to clueless customers' complaints, to provide easy answers and reduce cost of their developer support.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - It would be primitive if that were the only thing provided. However, if you are getting both (parsed argv + raw commandline, how is that primitive? It's useful if you have to do the exact thing which the OP asked about - passing the arguments through to a different program. If not for it, you would have to do the primitive thing to concatenating argv back to recreate the original full argument.

Comment: @user93353, but then the other program (or the CreateProcess function more likely) has to re-parse the string. If you wanted to slightly modify the arguments for the new process, to add or remove something, you have to care about quoting and escaping. The  `execv()` family of functions allow you to pass an array of arguments that are already split into separate words, which is much safer (no quoting or escaping problems possible.) It was a solved problem long before Windows existed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Haha, does a "problem" exist if the solution precedes it? It's nice to have a platform for people who want functions such as this to exist. Certainly it reduces the noise level in the UNIX world.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - _execv also exists on windows - My basic question is how is it primitive to provide more choices?

Comment: @user93353 I think he means not "primitive" as a building block for complex things, but "primitive" as something only a caveman would do.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Yes - I understood that from the beginning. He meant it as a criticism - Windows users use caveman like methods for processing command lines. However it's a silly criticism - because argc/argv way also exists.

Comment: Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.  On UNIX you can't customize the parsing of the command line to accommodate your preferred syntax; you're forced to make your syntax compatible with the shell's conventions.  I believe Windows inherits its approach from CP/M which evolved at around the same time as UNIX.

Comment: @user93353: there are compatibility issues; code using the UNIX-like approach (argc/argv) can't easily handle complicated command lines, because the shell doesn't have any way to provide a consistent quoting mechanism to override the default parsing.  (This is typically only a problem for UNIX applications ported over to Windows; Perl is perhaps the best canonical example.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston `GetCommandLine` does nothing more than putting all the arguments, including whitespace, into a single argument. And most shells allow the argument separator to be adjusted to simplify such a situation for the user. On the other hand, `GetCommandLine` may place unforseen burdens on the application, for example now script comments must have some syntax. And it essentially eliminates the possibility of shells doing things differently, since the app will only emulate PowerShell.

Comment: It's subjective.  A cultural difference, you might say.  Personally, I see no advantage and several disadvantages to having the details of the command-line syntax for a particular application depend on the shell used to invoke it, but I understand that many people prefer it that way.  (Perhaps the difference in approach can be summarized as "Windows puts the onus on the programmer; UNIX puts the onus on the user.")  I'm not sure what you mean about script comments, are you objecting to the fact that they can't be on the same line as a command?

Comment: (It should also be kept in mind that Windows and UNIX use their shells very differently.  The traditional Windows shells are blunt instruments, not meant to be used for serious programming.  PowerShell is more complete, but it's designed primarily for use with cmdlets, WMI, and PowerShell extensions rather than with command-line applications.  The whole "shell out to another executable and let it take care of things" is a traditional UNIX approach, but not a traditional Windows one; Windows applications are supposed to use the API.)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: CreateProcess does not parse the command string, except (in some cases) to determine which executable to invoke.  In Windows, it is definitely the responsibility of the application to parse the command line.  In practice, the runtime library typically takes care of it unless the application has special needs.

Comment: Another quick note, to make sure nobody gets misled: the string returned by GetCommandLine is most definitely not sanitized in any way.  If you're passing an untrusted string to CreateProcess, you're probably doing something wrong, but if you absolutely must, you need to sanitize it yourself.  Of course, you have to understand the syntax of the child application in order to do this.

Comment: From some other stackoverflow answers, apparently `/proc/${PID}/cmdline` on Linux can also show a *more* raw form than argv/argc, where spaces between tokens were replaced with nulls, but quotes should be preserved. So one *should* be able to reconcatenate them more reliably. Though I lack a current Linux installation to verify this (and so I'm not writing it as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I turn the command line back into shell args.   Sometime this is nice to echo into an output file, to save "what arguments were used" along with the output.   The escaping is rudimentary, and sufficient for most situations.

I started the output at the command (i=0).   You can change to (i=1) if you want arguments only, etc.

```
//you have to free() the result!, returns null if no args
char *arg2cmd(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *buf=NULL;
    int n = 0;
    int k, i;
    for (i=0; i <argc;++i) {
        int k=strlen(argv[i]);
        buf=( char *)realloc(buf,n+k+4);
        char *p=buf+n;
        char endq=0;
        // this is a poor mans quoting, which is good enough for anything that's not rediculous
        if (strchr(argv[i], ' ')) {
            if (!strchr(argv[i], '\'')) {
                *p++='\'';
                endq='\'';
            } else {
                *p++='\"';
                endq='\"';
            }
        }
        memcpy(p, argv[i], k);
        p+=k;
        if (i < (argc-1)) *p++=' ';
        if (endq) *p++=endq;
        *p='\0';
        n = p-buf;
    }
    return buf;
}
```

And a simple cpp wrapper:

```
std::string arg2string(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *tmp=arg2cmd(argc, argv);
    std::string ret=tmp;
    free(tmp);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++/CLI there's this:

```
String^ cmdarg = Environment::CommandLine;
```